# recommendProductsForUsers not working in Spark 1.5.0

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

Given the following:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, Rating
r1 = (1, 1, 1.0)
r2 = (1, 2, 2.0)
r3 = (2, 1, 2.0)
ratings = sc.parallelize([r1, r2, r3])
model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, 1, seed=10)

res = model.recommendProductsForUsers(2)
```

I'd like to compute the top k products for every user. In general, users and products could be many and it would be too expensive to create an RDD to use with recommendProducts.

According to [Spark version 1.5.0](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.recommendation) `recommendProductsForUsers` should do the job. However, I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c65e6875ea5b> in <module>()
      7 model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, 1, seed=10)
      8 
----> 9 res = model.recommendProductsForUsers(2)

AttributeError: 'MatrixFactorizationModel' object has no attribute 'recommendProductsForUsers'
```

And, in fact, `recommendProductsForUsers` does not appear when listing the methods of matrixFactorizationModel:

```
print dir(model)
['__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_java_loader_class', '_java_model', '_load_java', '_sc', 'call', 'load', 'predict', 'predictAll', 'productFeatures', 'rank', 'recommendProducts', 'recommendUsers', 'save', 'userFeatures']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong documentation. A simple fact that some operation is implemented in a Scala or Java API it doesn't mean it is exposed to PySpark. If you check [PySpark 1.5 API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel) you'll see it doesn't provide requested method.

[`recommendUsersForProducts`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/python/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.py#L187) and [`recommendProductsForUsers`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/python/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.py#L181) have been introduced in PySpark 1.6 with [SPARK-10535](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10535).

Comment: it is. see here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.recommendation

Comment: Could you accept the answer? There is no reason to keep this open anymore. Thanks.